# iOS 8.3 UIApplication sendEvent: issues

Tags: ios

How is `sendEvent:` never invoked? It worked in 8.2, and now it doesn't in 8.3.  `App_delegate` is completely striped, it just initializes and sets a `UIWindow` and `ViewControlller`.

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include  "App_delegate.h"

@interface Fs_application : UIApplication
@end

@implementation Fs_application

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"got event");
    if ([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches)
        [(App_delegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] touchEvent:event];
    else
        [super sendEvent: event];
}

@end

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([Fs_application class]),
                NSStringFromClass([App_delegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: out of interest why are you subclassing UIApplication?

Comment: This is going to be one of those times where I will feel stupid once someone points out something simple I overlooked..

Comment: @Woodstock for a game - this is easiest way to grab touches as soon as they are available

Comment: @matt override now, or wait for event to be passed to window and override there - whats the difference other than saving a little time?

Comment: @matt Realistically - it's not like making that change will effect (affect?) my game; but I'm just really curious why this in particular isn't working. I will likely just switch to UIWindow when I get over it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I take back the question. This *does* work in 8.3.

However, the events (not just touch events!) only get generated if `window.layer.contents` is not null (same as in 8.2, 8.1, ect). Why is this? I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: As you yourself said, "This is going to be one of those times where I will feel stupid once someone points out something simple I overlooked". It turns out the someone was you! I guess you had such an incomplete app scaffold that it didn't even qualify for event receipt. Thank you for solving this!